# How to tune OpenAi model to generate data

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a board game where all the players characteristics and rules are being randomised / generated. I’ve made a document to teach model - how game works, what characteristics it should generate and examples. How I can teach model with it? Tried GPT3-turbo but it has limit per conversation.

Used fine-tuned model. Thought I can send the info to it, so it remembers and uses it, but it has only prompt -> completion